# can I optimize my java prog by transposing a 2d array?

Tags: java, matrix, ram

I have:

```
final int ROWS = 100000;
final int COLS = 2000;
long[][] m = new long[COLS][ROWS];
```

and then:

```
public void xor(int row1, int row2) {
    for (int col=0; col<COLS; col++) {
        m[col][row1] ^= m[col][row2];
    }
}
```

The above function is, simplified, what takes most of the time in a run. I was wondering if I should invest time to refactor my whole program to read "m = new long[ROWS][COLS]" (instead of the other way around) for better RAM access. Or won't I win much time with it?

I am aware that I could parallellize it with perhaps GPU's, but that's for a later stage.

Comment: what are you trying to do? I can't answer unless I know more about the problem you are trying to solve by optimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it will definitely help to swap ROWS and COLS.

The layout of this arrays is (roughly) like this: [0][0], [0][1], [0][2],... [1][0], [1][1],... and so on. In your code, each column is a continuous chunk of memory, and a row is not.

Since each column is 800000 bytes, and in your `xor` method you access all of them, you are forcing more cache misses.

After transposing, each row becomes a continuous piece of memory, and since you tend to operate on rows, it should make it faster.

If you had `long[][] m = new long[ROWS][COLS];` and `for (int col=0; col<COLS; col++) m[row1][col] ^= m[row2][col];`, you'd only need two 16000-byte-long rows to be in the cache during the execution of the `xor` method.

But since what I said is based mostly on theory, try to benchmark both variants and check which one is really faster.

Comment: That numbers make sense. It sounds like it's worth trying, so I will. Results will follow later.

Comment: Good call! An iteration of my main loop used to cost 8 hours. Now it's 3 hours :). Interesting sidenote: initialization of memory (m = new int[..][..]) went up from 20s to 4 minutes (I don't know why).

Comment: Maybe it's because since you have more rows now, you're creating more `long[]` objects.